# Force mixed result from DQL select

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a dql query like this

```
"SELECT a, b FROM EntityA a JOIN a.variable b"
```

and I would like Doctrine gives me a list of results where each entry is an array(object(EntityA), object(EntityB)). So I'm sure the two objects "a" and "b" are the ones related.

Actually, when I run this query I get a list of separated objects "a" and "b" like (I use the {} notation for representing the list)

{object(EntityA), object(EntityB), object(EntityA), object(EntityB), ...}

and I don't want to rely on the fact that in the odd position there are EntityA objects and in the even position EntityB objects. That's absolutely not reliable.  I would like retrieve a list like

{array(object(EntityA), object(EntityB)), array(object(EntityA), object(EntityB)), ...}

Now, I know I obtain a mixed result if I select **ONE** Entity + n scalar value, like

```
"SELECT a, b.id AS b_id FROM EntityA a JOIN a.variable b"
```

and the result is

{array(object(EntityA), 'b_id' => *value*}, array(object(EntityA), 'b_id' => *value*}, ...}

but does anyone know how to force this mixed result where more than one entites are selected?

**Note1**: hydrating the results as objects or array doesn't change

**Note2**: from the Doctrine documentation, the section "[Fetching Multiple FROM Entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#fetching-multiple-from-entities)" reports

> If you fetch multiple entities that are listed in the FROM clause then the hydration will return the rows iterating the different top-level entities.

So, maybe I should try another approach, but I don't know what

**Note3**: I tried the trick (multiple entities + a dummy scalar)

```
"SELECT a, b, 1 AS b_id FROM EntityA a JOIN a.variable b"
```

but it does not work properly

**Note4**: I don't want to access "b" from "a". To make it simple I showed them directly associated, but in my case are indirectly associated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is arbitrary joins (supported as of Doctrine ORM 2.3):

```
SELECT
    a,
    b
FROM
    EntityA a
JOIN
    EntityB b
WITH
    b.aReference = a.id
```

Where I assume that `aReference` is either a `ManyToOne` or `OneToOne` marked field referencing `EntityA`.

The result from this operation will be an array with following pseudo-structure:

```
[
    [a1, b1],
    [a1, b2],
    [a1, b3],
    [a2, b1],
    [a2, b4],
    [a3, b5],
    // etc.
]
```

Comment: This gives me [a1,b1,a2,b2]. It would be great to get the format you have posted.